# php fetch data multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

i'm new on php and i have a problem to fetch some data on mysql.

I need to fetch the information that are stored in 3 different tables, i managed to get the data but i have a problem how i fetch the result.

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT bike.id, bike.photo, bike.gallery, bike.motorbike_id,  bike.privacy,
           bike.nickname, bike.data_acquire, dets.name, dets.company, dets.release_year, 
           dets.displacement, dets.horsepower, dets.type, pers.id, pers.name, pers.photo, 
           pers.cost, pers.type, pers.date_acquire, manu.id, manu.cost, manu.name, manu.date
           FROM mt_userbikes AS bike
           LEFT JOIN mt_motorbikes AS dets ON dets.id = bike.motorbike_id
           LEFT JOIN mt_userbike_personalizations AS pers ON pers.userbike_id = bike.id
           LEFT JOIN mt_userbike_maintenances AS manu ON manu.userbike_id = bike.id
           WHERE bike.id = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("i", $motorBikeId);
if ($stmt->execute()) {

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $photo, $gallery, $motorbike_id, $privacy, $nickname, 
                       $data_acquire, $motoName, $motoCompany, $motoReleaseYear, 
                       $motoDisplacement, $motoHorsepower, $motoType, $persId, 
                       $persName, $persPhoto, $persCost, $persType, $persDateAcquire, 
                       $manuId, $manuCost, $manuName, $manuDate);

    $data = array();
    $other = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($i === 0) {
            $data["id"] = $id;
            $data["photo"] = $photo;
            $data["gallery"] = $gallery;
            $data["motorbikeId"] = $motorbike_id;
            $data["privacy"] = $privacy;
            $data["nickname"] = $nickname;
            $data["dataAcquire"] = $data_acquire;
            $info = array();
            $info["name"] = $motoName;
            $info["company"] = $motoCompany;
            $info["releaseYear"] = $motoReleaseYear;
            $info["displacement"] = $motoDisplacement;
            $info["horsepower"] = $motoHorsepower;
            $info["type"] = $motoType;
            $data["info"] = $info;
        }
        $values = array();
        $values["pers.id"] = $persId;
        $values["pers.name"] = $persName;
        $values["pers.photo"] = $persPhoto;
        $values["pers.cost"] = $persCost;
        $values["pers.type"] = $persType;
        $values["pers.date_acquire"] = $persDateAcquire;
        $values["manu.id"] = $manuId;
        $values["manu.cost"] = $manuCost;
        $values["manu.name"] = $manuName;
        $values["manu.date"] = $manuDate;
        $other[$i] = $values;
        $i++;
    }
    $data["other"] = $other;
```

This is how I get the results now:

```
{
"id": 1,
"photo": null,
"gallery": null,
"motorbikeId": 1,
"privacy": null,
"nickname": "maro",
"dataAcquire": null,
"info": {
    "name": "MT-07",
    "company": "Yamaha",
    "releaseYear": 2013,
    "displacement": "689 cc",
    "horsepower": "55,0 kW (74,8CV)",
    "type": "Naked"
},
"other": [
    {
        "pers.id": 1,
        "pers.name": "cupolino",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 100,
        "pers.type": "accessorio",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 1,
        "manu.cost": 80,
        "manu.name": "controllo annuale",
        "manu.date": "2015-07-28"
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 2,
        "pers.name": "copriradiatore",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 80,
        "pers.type": "accessorio estetico",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 1,
        "manu.cost": 80,
        "manu.name": "controllo annuale",
        "manu.date": "2015-07-28"
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 3,
        "pers.name": "protezioni laterale radiatore sportive",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 100.5,
        "pers.type": "accessorio estetico",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 1,
        "manu.cost": 80,
        "manu.name": "controllo annuale",
        "manu.date": "2015-07-28"
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 4,
        "pers.name": "copri avviatore",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 15,
        "pers.type": "accessorio estetito",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 1,
        "manu.cost": 80,
        "manu.name": "controllo annuale",
        "manu.date": "2015-07-28"
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 1,
        "pers.name": "cupolino",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 100,
        "pers.type": "accessorio",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 2,
        "manu.cost": 100,
        "manu.name": "controllo 1000km",
        "manu.date": "2014-09-02"
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 2,
        "pers.name": "copriradiatore",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 80,
        "pers.type": "accessorio estetico",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 2,
        "manu.cost": 100,
        "manu.name": "controllo 1000km",
        "manu.date": "2014-09-02"
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 3,
        "pers.name": "protezioni laterale radiatore sportive",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 100.5,
        "pers.type": "accessorio estetico",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 2,
        "manu.cost": 100,
        "manu.name": "controllo 1000km",
        "manu.date": "2014-09-02"
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 4,
        "pers.name": "copri avviatore",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 15,
        "pers.type": "accessorio estetito",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
        "manu.id": 2,
        "manu.cost": 100,
        "manu.name": "controllo 1000km",
        "manu.date": "2014-09-02"
    }
]
}
```

what I want to get

```
{
"id": 1,
"photo": null,
"gallery": null,
"motorbikeId": 1,
"privacy": null,
"nickname": "maro",
"dataAcquire": null,
"info": {
    "name": "MT-07",
    "company": "Yamaha",
    "releaseYear": 2013,
    "displacement": "689 cc",
    "horsepower": "55,0 kW (74,8CV)",
    "type": "Naked"
},
"personalizations": [
    {
        "pers.id": 1,
        "pers.name": "cupolino",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 100,
        "pers.type": "accessorio",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
    },
    {
        "pers.id": 2,
        "pers.name": "copriradiatore",
        "pers.photo": null,
        "pers.cost": 80,
        "pers.type": "accessorio estetico",
        "pers.date_acquire": null,
    }
    ...
 ]
"maintenances": [
    {
        "manu.id": 1,
        "manu.cost": 80,
        "manu.name": "controllo annuale",
        "manu.date": "2015-07-28"
    },
    {
        "manu.id": 2,
        "manu.cost": 100,
        "manu.name": "controllo 1000km",
        "manu.date": "2014-09-02"
    }
    ...
 ]
}
```

how can i distinguish the rows from one table to another? 
i hope that what i did is not stupid, if so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast approach to your task

```
 $pers = array();
 $manu = array();
$i = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($i === 0) {
        $data["id"] = $id;
        $data["photo"] = $photo;
        $data["gallery"] = $gallery;
        $data["motorbikeId"] = $motorbike_id;
        $data["privacy"] = $privacy;
        $data["nickname"] = $nickname;
        $data["dataAcquire"] = $data_acquire;
        $info = array();
        $info["name"] = $motoName;
        $info["company"] = $motoCompany;
        $info["releaseYear"] = $motoReleaseYear;
        $info["displacement"] = $motoDisplacement;
        $info["horsepower"] = $motoHorsepower;
        $info["type"] = $motoType;
        $data["info"] = $info;
    }
    $values = array();
    $values["pers.id"] = $persId;
    $values["pers.name"] = $persName;
    $values["pers.photo"] = $persPhoto;
    $values["pers.cost"] = $persCost;
    $values["pers.type"] = $persType;
    $values["pers.date_acquire"] = $persDateAcquire;
    $pers[] = $values;
   $values = array()
    $values["manu.id"] = $manuId;
    $values["manu.cost"] = $manuCost;
    $values["manu.name"] = $manuName;
    $values["manu.date"] = $manuDate;
    $manu[] = $values;
    $i++;
}
$data["personalizations"] = unique($pers); 
$data["maintenances"] = unique($manu)

function unnique(){ /*look on attached link*/ }
```

Unique function for multi dimensional array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/946300/2685996)